# Generate tiles when creating tile Layer on ArcGIS Enterprise Portal

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I have a raster (TIFF) that I want to publish on my ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. To reach that aim, I followed these steps :

1)  Create SDDraft from TIFF in ArcGIS Pro project

2) Create SD file from the draft

3) Publish Tile Layer from SD file

```
import arcpy
from atmo.connect import *
from shutil import copyfile

import os


######################
#connexion au portail Cartothèque
arcgisPortal_arcpy_conn()

# Set output file names
dir = 'K:/WEB-SIG/PROD/URBAINE'
annee = '2018'
ville = 'LILLE'
outdir = dir + '/%s/%s' %(ville,annee)
print(outdir)

print('Publication des données pour ' + ville + ' et l\'année ' + annee)
service = ville + "_"+annee+"_PM25_moy"
print('Publication des données de ' + service)
sddraft_file = outdir + '\\' + service + '.sddraft'

##### ETAPE 1 - Création du fichier SDDraft depuis un projet ArcGIS Pro

# Reference map to publish
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(dir + r"/ARCGIS_projects/" + ville + '/' + ville + ".aprx")
map = aprx.listMaps("PM25_moy")[0]

# Create Tile Layer SharingDraft from map in ArcGisPro project
sharing_draft = map.getWebLayerSharingDraft("HOSTING_SERVER", "TILE", service)
print('Le brouillon de la WebLayer est créé.')

# Create Service Definition Draft file
sharing_draft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_file)
print('Le fichier du brouillon du service de Définition est créé')


##### ETAPE 2 - Création du fichier SD (Service Definition) depuis le fichier SDDraft

# Create Service definition file
sd_file = outdir + '\\' + service + ".sd"
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft_file, sd_file)
print('Le fichier de Service définition est créé')


##### ETAPE 3 - Publication de la couche de tuiles depuis le fichier SD

# Share to portal as Tile Layer
print("Uploading Service Definition...")
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_file, "My Hosted Services")  

print("Successfully Uploaded service.")
```

It works well, my Tile Layer is created, but the tiles are not generated.
I tried to publish them this way, with the gis package :

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# Envoi des requêtes de mise à jour de tuiles.
print("Lancement de la mise à jour des tuiles.")
#on vérifie que la TL existe
if portal.content.search("title: %s_%s_PM25_moy" % (ville,annee), "Map Image Layer") !=[]:
    layer = portal.content.search("title: %s_%s_PM25_moy" % (ville,annee), "Map Image Layer")[0]
    print(layer)
    mapImageLayer = mapping.MapImageLayer(layer.url, portal)
    mapImageLayer.manager.update_tiles()
    print('Update des tiles en cours')
```

But I do not find a function to generate the tiles, only to update them.

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Tile Packages are produced from ArcGIS Pro by using the [Create Map Tile Package (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm) geoprocessing tool which is available from ArcPy.  The documentation includes Python syntax examples. Once the tile package is produced, you can publish it using Python.